# Maven in Jenkins : Doesn't find any test

Tags: maven, jenkins, integration-testing, junit5

I'm trying to run automatised test on Jenkins with Maven. However, when I use the command "mvn test" in a Maven Project Job, the console return me that's no test was found.

The path to my test files respect the convention (I think) and are at src/test/java/Gui/CameraTest.java

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>GoSecuri</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>13</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>13</maven.compiler.target>
        <jenkins.e2eTests.reportsDirectory>target/protractor-reports</jenkins.e2eTests.reportsDirectory>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1-1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-M5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-M5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
            <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can anyone help me pls ?

Comment: Do they run locally? I feel that you are mixing Junit4 and JUnit5 here. Therefore your surefire plugins try to run JUnit4 tests but you defined JUnit5 tests. Try running maven locally and see if any tests are ran

Comment: Hi, yes it's running locally. The difference is that in localy my IDE IntelliJ will automaticaly give the dependencies but in Jenkins I need to give myself the dependencies for Maven in the pom.xml

Comment: Remove the junit-platform-surefire-provider. Second use a more recent version of JUnit Jupiter (5.6.2) furthermore upgrade maven-surefire-plugin to at least 2.22.2. Apart from that you should use lowercase package names.

Comment: Fair enough it seem to work for me ! Thx khmarbaise

Answer (score 1):

maven-surefire-plugin
2.19

add this piece and try to build from testng.xml and don't forget to add your runner class to your testng.xml

```
<configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/runners/testNG/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
```